# Sending CSV files to MS Sentinel

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, azure-sentinel

I am trying to upload files from S3 Bucket to azure sentinel. The files in S3 created during create-export-task which are of document kind , which is not supported by azure sentinel while polling the message once we send an s3 trigger event to SNS. Since there are multiple files, with task-id in the path, it makes it difficult to retrieve the path each time to convert all the files(using lambda function)
I need to implement the conversion of files in s3 from document kind to CSV/JSON so that it can be collected by the Azure Sentinel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the post with the details